# Number pattern with user-input lines

Tags: python

The program should print something like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1    
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

(but there's no space between each line)

The lines should be a user-input.

```
lines = int(input("enter lines: "))
times = int(input("enter times: "))
for x in range(1,lines+1):
    for x in range(1,times+1):
        print(x, end=" ")
    print(x)
```

The program I made doesn't print it the output, and it seems that it was reversed. and it must be derived from the program that prints asterisks which is this:

```
lines = int(input("enter lines: "))
times = int(input("enter times: "))
for x in range(lines):
    for x in range(times):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

And it asks what line of program was changed. Thank you

Comment: Why are you using the same loop variable for _both_ loops?

Comment: Change the inner loop to `for y in range(1,times+1): print(x, end=' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes in your code:

-Do not use same iterator variable in nested for loops

-in for loop where you are just using `print(x)` will print additional value instead of printing next line so you can use condition for that if it's a last value then end by new line otherwise space

```
lines = int(input("enter lines: "))
times = int(input("enter times: "))
for i in range(1,lines+1):
    for j in range(1,times+1):
        if j == times:
            print(i, end="\n")
        else:
            print(i, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much more simpler

```
lines = 7
times = 7
for i in range(1,times+1):
    print(' {}'.format(str(i)*lines))
```

But you can take the input from the user for the lines and times.

**Output**

```
 1111111
 2222222
 3333333
 4444444
 5555555
 6666666
 7777777
```